# Cannot access mongodb inside docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am currently containerizing my application inside docker. I have two images one for my node application and another for mongodb. I have link two using docker-compose. But whenever I try accessing mongodb inside container using the port 27017. 
But it displays like this:
**

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native
>   driver port.

**
I have mongodb config as:

```
 "url": "mongodb://mongoDB/astroDB"
```

My docker-compose file is as :

```
version: '3.0'
services:
web:
    image: astrobot-node
    build: .
    command: "yarn start"
    ports: 
        - "80:3601"
    depends_on:
        - "mongo"
mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

Can anyone tell me what's actually wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> But whenever I try accessing mongodb inside container using the port 27017. But it displays like this: **

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

This is expected behavior if you try to send HTTP requests to the MongoDB port. What this says to me  is you got your network connectivity figured out and that part is working correctly.

Next you just need to use a MongoDB driver to talk to the database from the application instead of hitting it with `curl` or similar.

Comment: I am using the monogdb driver connection for connecting my application to mongodb. I tried posting data using POSTMAN it won't work

Answer (score 1):

the standard mangodb connection url should look like this

`mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

In you case the **mongoDB** in your url string should indicate the db host, To make it points to the mangodb container you should change it to `"url": "mongodb://mongo/astroDB"`, cause your service named **mango** not **mangoDB**.

you can also achieve that by provide a static IP to your container and write this IP directly, you can also find you container network IP by using the `docker container inspect <container-IP>` to test it manually.

**EDIT**

Here is a thread that should help you debugging your problem.
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-mongodb-work-in-docker-how-to-connect-with-mongodb/44763/8